# Help with my printf function

Tags: c, printf

For debugging purposes I would like to have a printf_debug function that would function just like the standard printf function, but would only print if a #DEFINE DEBUG was true

I know I have to use varagrs (...) but I have no idea how to actually achieve that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easier to just #define it away. Something like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define printf_debug printf
#else
#define printf_debug while(0)printf
#endif
```

Comment: Didn't remember that. That's a useful answer, however, I would like to know how to achieve what I asked with varargs. Thanks anyway. Vote up.

Comment: why is there a 'printf' after 'while(0)'?

Comment: @Gary - if there wasn't, you'd get a syntax error when compiling in non-debug mode because of the arguments being passed to printf

Comment: hmmm... maybe it's being optimised away? i've tried it with ints as well as strings, still no error.

Comment: Yes, amusingly you don't need the printf... it turns into an expression using the comma operator.

Answer (score 2):

I don't what exactly you want to achieve. In case you want a code block to execute only if `DEBUG` is defined, use the preprocessor directive `#ifdef`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#define DEBUG

void printf_debug(const char *format, ...) {
  #ifdef DEBUG
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, format);
  vprintf(format, args);
  va_end(args);
  #endif /* DEBUG */
}
```

Comment: I know that's the "idea" for the function, but that code doesn't actully compiles. Would you mind providing a working function? Thanks.

Comment: The #ifdef will always be true. The arguments to printf_debug aren't valid (a ... can only follow a real argument). The arguments aren't passed to printf. There's a missing semicolon after the printf statement. The printf is commented out. It's commented out with // which is not standard C.

Comment: I know, I was demonstrating the use of #ifdef. I'll edit this in a minute.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use vargs, macros will work. Here is an example, which will prints function and line number as well:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define printf_debug(fmt, args...) printf("%s[%d]: "fmt, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##args)
#else
#define printf_debug(fmt, args...)
#endif
```

The ##args here will be replaced by the args list, which likes what vargs does in function call.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the va_arg macros, they are used to access the variadic variables. A useful link: http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/other/va_arg. The reference is for C++, but these macros can be used in C as well.

In your actual implementation you place the code using the variadic variables in a `#ifdef` block.

But if you're looking for a regular call to printf, dependent on `DEBUG` a simple `#define` acting as an alias will do.

Comment: Upvoted, but you should mention #include <stdarg.h>, since the reference you gave uses the C++ version <cstdarg>

Comment: The link refers to functions but i think nunos wanted an answer in regard to macros. In which case varidic macros were only added in C99.

Answer (score 0):

C99 compiler only!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEBUG

#ifdef DEBUG
 #define debug(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
 #define debug while(0)
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    debug("Only shows when DEBUG is defined!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

to be honest varidic macros are not needed you could just easily write it as this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEBUG

#ifdef DEBUG
 #define debug printf
#else
 #define debug while(0)
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    debug("Only shows when DEBUG is defined!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Thinking about it, debug information should go to stderr so as not to interfer with stdout, so this one should be favoured:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEBUG

#ifdef DEBUG
 #define debug(...) fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
#else
 #define debug while(0)
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    debug("Only shows when DEBUG is defined!\n");
    return 0;
}
```